# PHP Old value for select option with free-text

Tags: php, html-select

I have a select option with free text option like
[this radio button with free text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8a7z.png)

```
<div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group row @error('warna') has-error @enderror">
        <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Buta Warna</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type=radio id="warna1" name="warna" value="Negatif"
                @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)){{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Negatif' ? 'checked' : ''}}@endif>
            Negatif</option><br>
            <input type=radio id="warna2" name="warna" value="Partial"
                @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)){{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Partial' ? 'checked' : ''}}@endif>
            Partial</option><br>
            <input type=radio id="warna3" name="warna" value="Total"
                @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)){{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Total' ? 'checked' : ''}}@endif>
            Total</option><br>
            <input type=radio id="warna4" name="warna" value="Other" @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi))
                @if($mcu_form_tensi->warna != 'Negatif' && $mcu_form_tensi->warna != 'Partial' &&
            $mcu_form_tensi->warna != 'Total') checked @endif @endif> Other</option><br>

            <input id="txt_warna_other" type="text" name="warna" placeholder=""
                class="form-control @error('warna') has-error @enderror" autocomplete="warna"
                value="@if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)) {{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna }} @endif"
                @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)) @if($mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Negatif' ||
            $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Partial' || $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Total') readonly @endif
            @endif>


            @error('warna')
            <div class="text-danger">
                <small>{{ $message }}</small>
            </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wasn't able to retain old value if validation failed for a new record.
it keeps reverting back to choose none, so the user must choose again.
please, help so the user doesn't need to input again, they only input those invalid inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my working code

```
<div class="form-group row @error('warna') has-error @enderror">
    <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Buta Warna</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type=radio id="warna1" name="warna" value="Negatif"
            @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)){{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Negatif' ? 'checked' : ''}}
            @elseif(old('warna')=='Negatif' ) checked @endif>
        Negatif</option><br>
        <input type=radio id="warna2" name="warna" value="Partial"
            @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)){{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Partial' ? 'checked' : ''}}
            @elseif(old('warna')=='Partial' ) checked @endif>
        Partial</option><br>
        <input type=radio id="warna3" name="warna" value="Total"
            @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)){{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Total' ? 'checked' : ''}}
            @elseif(old('warna')=='Total' ) checked @endif>
        Total</option><br>
        <input type=radio id="warna4" name="warna" value="Other" @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi))
            @if($mcu_form_tensi->warna != 'Negatif' && $mcu_form_tensi->warna != 'Partial' &&
        $mcu_form_tensi->warna != 'Total') checked @endif @elseif(old('warna') != 'Negatif' &&
        old('warna') != 'Partial' && old('warna') != 'Total')
        checked @endif> Other</option><br>
        <input id="txt_warna_other" type="text" name="warna" placeholder=""
            class="form-control @error('warna') has-error @enderror" autocomplete="warna"
            value="@if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)) {{ $mcu_form_tensi->warna }} @else {{old('warna')}}@endif"
            @if(isset($mcu_form_tensi)) @if($mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Negatif' ||
        $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Partial' || $mcu_form_tensi->warna == 'Total') readonly @endif
        @endif>
        @error('warna')
        <div class="text-danger">
            <small>{{ $message }}</small>
        </div>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this helps others too